# Two Arduino class instances returning same values

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm writing my first code for an Uno and have run into a problem using libraries.  I create two instances of my GPSLocation class (loc1 and loc2) to store lat and lon for two locations.  When I assign values to them, then recall them immediately, both instances hold the same values, those of the last object I set the values to.  I've been looking at this for hours and can't see what I've done wrong.

My code is below. Any help would be great.

**Test.ino**

```
void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {

    GpsLocation loc1;
    loc1.setLat(-12.3456);
    loc1.setLon(34.4567);
    GpsLocation loc2;
    loc2.setLat(-78.9123);
    loc2.setLon(187.6325);
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print("Loc1: ");
    Serial.print(loc1.getLat(), 4);
    Serial.print(", ");
    Serial.print(loc1.getLon(), 4);
    Serial.print("\n");
    Serial.print("Loc2: ");
    Serial.print(loc2.getLat(), 4);
    Serial.print(", ");
    Serial.print(loc2.getLon(), 4);
    Serial.print("\n");
}
```

**GPSLocation.h**

```
#ifndef GpsLocation_h
#define GpsLocation_h

#include "Arduino.h"

class GpsLocation
{
  public:
   GpsLocation();
   void setLat(float lat);
   void setLon(float lon);
   float getLat();
   float getLon();
};

#endif
```

**GPSLocation.cpp**

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "GpsLocation.h"

float latitude = 0.0;
float longitude = 0.0;

GpsLocation::GpsLocation(){}

void GpsLocation::setLat(float lat)
{
    latitude = lat;
}

void GpsLocation::setLon(float lon)
{
    longitude = lon;
}

float GpsLocation::getLat()
{
    return latitude;
}

float GpsLocation::getLon()
{
    return longitude;
}
```

This is what Serial Monitor returns

```
Loc1: -78.9123, 187.6325
Loc2: -78.9123, 187.6325
```

Comment: Make `latitude` and `longitude` members of `GpsLocation`.

Comment: Yep, looks like your longitude and latitude are defined as global variables - they're not defined in the GPSLocation class - hence only one copy of them exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my GPSLocation class as follows which solved my problem.  Thanks guys.

**GPSLocation.h**

```
#ifndef GpsLocation_h
#define GpsLocation_h

#include "Arduino.h"

class GpsLocation
{
  public:
   float latitude;
   float longitude;
};

#endif
```

**GPSLocation.cpp**

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "GpsLocation.h"
```

Setting and getting from **Test.ino** as follows

```
loc1.latitude = -12.3456;
Serial.print(loc1.latitude, 4);
```

Comment: you should accept your answer to indicate that your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem on your initial code is that you have defined your variables as global (in global scope), and they are accessible to both instances, hence the last value applied to them from any instance affects and is accessible to all instances.

In general, you should avoid using global variables, as it is considered a bad practice.

By making the variables non-static class members, you practically make them "parts" of your instances. That way, each Arduino instance has its own copy of variables in a sense and you can apply values separately.

UPDATE: In order to preserve encapsulation, it is also better to declare your variables as private and apply access to them via setter and getter methods. Take a look about the concept on [wiki](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)) for more.